# Inconsistent spelling of tags

Tags: discussion, tags, transliteration

I noticed that some of the tags that are made up using transliterated Hebrew words are not spelled consistently. For example, some of the tags in the general category of "hasidut" are spelled with an "h", and some are spelled without the "h".

Is this intentional? Can it be fixed?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/679/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, is there a reason you didn't close this as a duplicate? Seems clearly like one to me.

Comment: I just realized that may have sounded like I was reprimanding. I didn't mean it that way. I was, rather, checking whether there's a reason to keep this open, so I don't close it incorrectly.

Comment: @msh210 None (and I didn't take it that way). I just saw this as I was leaving my computer so I quickly posted it as a comment without reading through both carefully. I didn't even write "related" :)